# Strong Markov property and its meaning

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Given a sequence of random variables $(X_n)_n$ (fulfilling the Markov property) and a stopping time $\tau$ such that $P(\tau < \infty)=1$, we have that $P(X_{\tau+1}=x_1,X_{\tau+2}=x_2,...|X_{\tau}=x) = P(X_{1}=x_1,X_{2}=x_2,...|X_{0}=x)$. I don't understand where the stopping time comes into play. Why is it not equivalent to say that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: P(X_{n+1}=x_1,X_{n+2}=x_2,...|X_{n}=x) = P(X_{1}=x_1,X_{2}=x_2,...|X_{0}=x)$?

Comment: Note that in the left hand side of the equation you've wrote, $\tau$ itself is a *random variable*

Comment: and this means?

Comment: $P(X_{\tau+1}=x_1,X_{\tau+2}=x_2,...|X_{\tau}=x)$ is a probability that $\tau$ is not a constant in it. Indeed it's not exactly similar to $P(X_{n+1}=x_1,X_{n+2}=x_2,...|X_{n}=x)$ for a constant $n$.
Indeed $P(X_{\tau+1}=x_1,X_{\tau+2}=x_2,...|X_{\tau}=x)$ can be written by conditioning on the value of $\tau$.
I'm not sure i'm explaining well or not.